# Is there a postgres function to mutably update a binary data structure?

Tags: postgresql

I have written an `AGGREGATE` function that approximates a `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` over a `UUID` column, a kind of poor man's HyperLogLog (and having different perf characteristics).

However, it is very slow because I am using `set_bit` on a `BIT` and that has copy-on-write semantics.

So my question is:

1. is there a way to inplace / mutably update a `BIT` or `bytea`?
2. failing that, are there any binary data structures that allow mutable/in-place `set_bit` edits?

A constraint is that I can't push C code or extensions to implement this. But I can use extensions that are available in AWS RDS postgres. If it's not faster than HLL then I'll just be using HLL. Note that HLL is optimised for pre-aggregated counts, it isn't terribly fast at doing adhoc count estimates over millions of rows (although still faster than a raw `COUNT DISTINCT`).

Below is the code for context, probably buggy too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uuid_approx_count_distinct_sfunc (BIT(83886080), UUID)
RETURNS BIT(83886080) AS $$
DECLARE
   s BIT(83886080) := $1;
BEGIN
   IF s IS NULL THEN s := '0' :: BIT(83886080); END IF;
   RETURN set_bit(s, abs(mod(uuid_hash($2), 83886080)), 1);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uuid_approx_count_distinct_ffunc (BIT(83886080))
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
   i INTEGER := 83886079;
   s INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
   LOOP
     EXIT WHEN i < 0;
     IF get_bit($1, i) = 1 THEN s := s + 1; END IF;
     i := i - 1;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN s;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE approx_count_distinct (UUID) (
  SFUNC = uuid_approx_count_distinct_sfunc,
  FINALFUNC = uuid_approx_count_distinct_ffunc,
  STYPE = BIT(83886080),
  COMBINEFUNC = bitor,
  PARALLEL = SAFE
);
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL, `UPDATE` is *always* COW.

Comment: 1) `declare s alias for $1;` 2) `RETURN set_bit(coalesce(s, '0'::BIT(83886080)), abs(mod(uuid_hash($2), 83886080)), 1);` 3)

Comment: @Abelisto thanks that's a nice simplification. But unfortunately if `set_bit` cannot be made to inplace edit the value for performance, the code is moot anyway.

Comment: Think about `inout` parameter

Comment: @Abelisto that's interesting. I never knew about this feature. Unfortunately if I can't edit the `BIT` (or `bytea`) without triggering a copy-on-write then the parameter mode doesn't matter much. I'm really hoping there there is some hidden `set_bit_unsafe` function somewhere.

Comment: Please use proper parameter names for readability. There is really no reason to work with `$1` or `$2` any more

Comment: BTW: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=75138fda1c53b0d7b5eec1d57baa7172 "Execution Time: 0.029 ms"

Comment: @Abelisto the perf problem only really kicks in for lots of rows. e.g. my current test data has 2 million unique uuids out of 70 million rows. Now you raise a good point about  doing this with `int` and not `uuid` and I do indeed have a test where I precompute the hashes into a GENERATED column (I even did this for HLL) but that felt a little tangential to the question. Good ideas though.

Comment: Hmm... Probably it is silly question, but isn't counting of unique hash values will do the same job? `select count(distinct abs(mod(uuid_hash(<uuid_column>), 83886080))) from <table_name>;`? Having index on it could do the job even faster.

Comment: `COUNT DISTINCT` is known to be a slow operation at scale... which is the reason why I'm looking into doing it this way. HyperLogLog solves the same kind of problems but is optimised for storing intermediate precomputed count estimates that can be aggregated. I need to do it adhoc so I wanted to come up with a simple approach. Unfortunately, it seems I'd need some `internal` data structure so that I could mutate it and I can't have those in AWS RDS :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, SQL isn't actually that fast for raw computation. I might try a UDF, perhaps pljava or plv8 (JavaScript) which compile just-in-time to native and available on most major hosting providers. Of course for performance, use C (perhaps via LLVM) for maximum performance at maximum pain. Plv8 should take minutes to prototype, just pass an array constructed from array_agg(). Obviously keep the array size to millions of items, or find a way to roll-up your sketches ( bitwuse-AND ?)
https://plv8.github.io/#function-calls
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-array_agg-function/

FYI HyperLogLog is available as an open source extension for PostgreSQL from Citus/Microsoft and of course available on Azure. https://www.google.com/search?q=hyperloglog+postgres
(You could crib from their coffee and just change the core algorithm, then test side by side). Citus is pretty easy to install, so this isn't a bad option.

Comment: `plv8` is supported by AWS RDS so that opens up the possibility of writing an `internal` type for this, thanks!